# Multithreading in c++............how to execute?

Tags: c++, multithreading

I was learning multithreading in c++ on tutorialspoint.com where I came across this code:

```
#include<iostream>
#include<cstdlib>
#include<pthread.h>

using namespace std;

#define NUM_THREADS 5

void *PrintHello(void *threadnum)
{
    long int *tnum;
    tnum=(long*)threadnum;
    cout<<"Hello World! Thread num:"<<tnum<<endl;
    pthread_exit(NULL);
}

int main()
{
    pthread_t threads[NUM_THREADS];
    int rc;
    long int i;
    for(i=0;i<NUM_THREADS;i++)
    {
        cout<<"main(): creating thread,"<<i<<endl;
        rc=pthread_create(&threads[i],NULL,PrintHello,(void*)i);
        cout<<"Thread ID:"<<threads[i]<<endl;
        cout<<"-----------------------------------------------"<<endl;
        if(rc)
        {
            cout<<"Error:Unable to create thread,"<<rc<<endl;
            exit(-1);
        }
    }
    pthread_exit(NULL);
}
```

When I compiled this code I got my output as:

```
main(): creating thread,0
Thread ID:124028821706496
-----------------------------------------------
main(): creating thread,1
Thread ID:124028812797696
-----------------------------------------------
main(): creating thread,2
Hello World! Thread num:0
Thread ID:124028803434240
-----------------------------------------------
main(): creating thread,3
Hello World! Thread num:0x1
Hello World! Thread num:Thread ID:0x20x70cdb43d6700

-----------------------------------------------
main(): creating thread,4
Thread ID:124028785452800
Hello World! Thread num:0x4
-----------------------------------------------
Hello World! Thread num:0x3
```

My doubt is why I am getting this kind of output,I mean

```
cout<<"Hello World! Thread num:"<<tnum<<endl;
```

why this statement is not executing in order.what changes should be made??
Can somebody help me with this??

Comment: You have no control over when the threads actually run. If you want to synchronize the threads you need to use some kind of signaling the threads that they could all start, and even then it would be a race as to which thread starts running first.

Comment: You should look up how threading works. Try rerunning the code.

Comment: @JoachimPileborg, why it is like that??

Comment: Because that's how multi-tasking operating systems work. You ask the OS to create a thread, and it does and then the OS puts it in a queue as ready to run. However, before it actually starts running your main thread might run a little more, creating more threads. And when the OS decides to switch thread, it might not even be one from your process but from another process.

Comment: @JoachimPileborg, ok I got it. If I use mutex can it solve my problem??

Comment: Only if you want one thread at a time to run, and then what's the point of threads? You could use a condition variable, and then signal all waiting on that condition variable, but then you will have a race as to which thread will start first.

Comment: Also, the argument you pass to your thread function is not really a pointer, so `tnum` is not correctly declared.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There are a bunch of things wrong with your code. Also, before the code, there is a questionable decision to use POSIX threads instead of the default C++ threads. C++ threads generally integrate much better with C++ code than the ancient C API of POSIX threads. Reconsider that decision!

Now, to the defects:

- Don't use C-style casts. If you need, use the appropriate C++ cast (`static_cast`, `dynamic_cast`, `const_cast`, `reinterpret_cast`). In your case here, all you should need is `static_cast`. However, you might want to consider a pair of `reinterpret_cast`s here, too.
- `#define NUM_THREADS 5` should be `int const num_threads = 5;`. Don't use macros, search the web to find out why they are evil.
- `long int *tnum; tnum=(long*)threadnum;` Firstly, those two (declaration and initialization) should not be separate. Secondly, see the note about casts above.
- `pthread_exit(NULL);` You do that right before exiting the thread function itself. This has two effects: Firstly, it is completely redundant, because exiting the function (`return 0;`) does the same. Secondly, and here I'm not 100% sure, it probably skips the destructors of local variables. Think about the relevance that destructors take in the C++ object model and you will see that this is crucial to avoid. BTW: Using `NULL` was frowned upon long time ago already, using `0` was always preferred. With C++11, you even have a `nullptr` constant.
- `pthread_create(&threads[i],NULL,PrintHello,(void*)i);` apart from the obviously bad cast, consider the conversion made here. Then, look for the opposite conversion in the thread function. Hint: It isn't there, they are asymmetric.
- In `main()`, you `exit(-1);` or `pthread_exit(NULL);`. Why the difference? Why not use `return`? That said, one is for error handling, and for that, you should generally raise an exception in C++ code.
- Lastly, concerning the output, your assumptions are simply wrong. The threads operate independently, unless explicitly synchronized. Since you don't synchronize them in any way, the OS switches between different threads at will, even in the middle of a line of C++ code.